# How to sort logs by time with lambda function

Tags: python

I have a varriable

```
logs = """May 18 11:59:18 PC-00102 plasmashell[1312]: kf.plasma.core: findInCache with a lastModified timestamp of 0 is deprecated
May 20 13:06:54 ideapad kwin_x11[1273]: Qt Quick Layouts: Detected recursive rearrange. Aborting after two iterations.
May 20 09:16:28 PC0078 systemd[1]: Starting PackageKit Daemon...
May 20 11:01:12 PC-00102 PackageKit: daemon start
May 20 12:48:18 PC0078 systemd[1]: Starting Message of the Day...
May 21 14:33:55 PC0078 kernel: [221558.992188] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=1395, idProduct=0025, bcdDevice= 1.00
May 22 11:48:30 ideapad mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 3: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.3/usb1/1-4"
May 22 11:50:09 ideapad mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 3 was not an MTP device
May 23 08:06:14 PC-00233 kernel: [221559.381614] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
May 24 16:19:52 PC-00233 systemd[1116]: Reached target Sound Card.
May 24 19:26:40 PC-00102 rtkit-daemon[1131]: Supervising 5 threads of 2 processes of 1 users."""
```

I have to use lambda functions to sort this logs by time.
How can i do it?
thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a [questions and answers
site](https://stackoverflow.com/about), not a code-writing service. Please read
through [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [edit] your
question to reflect your work.

Comment: first split to lines using `split("\n")`, next split to parts (using `split(" ")` to get date and time, next convert date and time to object `datetime` and next you can create list with pairs `(datetime, line_of_text)` and you can sort it,.

Answer (score 1):

Using datetime to parse timestamps:

```py
import datetime
sorted_logs = "\n".join(sorted(logs.splitlines(), key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x[:15], "%b %d %H:%M:%S")))
```

Comment: your answer is wrong  
i resolved my case   

print(sorted(logs.split("\n"), key = lambda x: tuple(map(int, (x.split()[2].split(':'))))))

Comment: Interesting, why is it wrong?

Comment: Your answer does not take months nor days into account. Unless this is what you wanted but was not very explicit...

Comment: I agree with @jackylamouette - sorting without date can make wrong results in the future data. But this answer has one problem - it gets `x[:15]` so it will not work when months will have longer names - i.e. `February`

Comment: True, I was assuming that all logs would follow the same format as they look like standard system logs.